# boot XEN under UEFI-only BIOS

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, xen

Is there a way to get XEN 4.4 booting from UEFI mode BIOS? My AMD64bit laptop does not support direct CSM/legacy boots.

A nasty workaround has been to boot from a specially made USB pendrive with grub-efi-amd64-signed , which has proven problematic.

Linux Kernel 3.16.0-9-generic #14-Ubuntu SMP  x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
itself boots fine, except that it refuses to load the listed Xen kernels/hypervisors and loops right back to the Grub menu if tried.

BEWARE

There seems to be NO clear information from XenProject about EFI status, but through much blood and error it seems unsupported. This is the problem preventing my Xen-enabled kernel from loading:

```
Loading Xen 4.4-amd64 ...
error: Secure Boot forbids loading module from (hd0,gpt5)/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/multiboot.mod
```

Answer (score 0):

its sad no one helped here. in general I see a little help from the community for the crazy people who want to start a xen guest.